# Will I gain boost in performance if I stretch canvas in javascript? And is video rendering slower inside canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, video, canvas, stretch

Let's assume I run a HTML5 game on a 1920x1080 display.

If I set my canvas to be half of that 960x540, and stretch it to width and height of 100% via CSS, to run it fullscreen, will the game run faster?

Do I get effect like changing the actual resolution of a display?

(For those that don't know, CSS only stretches canvas, it does not set actual width and height of a canvas)

And one more question, is video rendering inside a canvas slower than normal video rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I set my canvas to be half of that 960x540, and stretch it to width and height of 100% via CSS, to run it fullscreen, will the game run faster?

With the size of *1920*1080 pixels* it won't do much difference because the context image data is natively bigger, containing *a lot* of RGBA colors. It'd be more faster to represent the graphics, but it'd be (more or less) slow to proccess the graphics yet (or fast, that depends on the user computer).

> Do I get effect like changing the actual resolution of a display?

This will depend on the user computer... Short answer, no.

> And one more question, is video rendering inside a canvas slower than normal video rendering?

Yes... The web video player is faster as it's native and contain less information about image data (colors format is RGB), etc.